# Anna Abhishekam to Lord Shiva on Full moon (Poornima thithi)

Tags: shiva, puranas, rituals, poornima

Yesterday being Poornima [full moon] Anna [rice] abhishekam was done to Lord Siva in many Siva temples in South India. In Thanjavur 1000 kgs of rice was done as annabhishekam to Lord Brahadeeswarar.

My question  -

- If this anna abhishekam is done every poornima [full moon] or on selected months poornima only? If so which months? and is there any scriptural  reference for this.
- Does this not apply to Vishnu or Brahma? Reasons why it is not applicable.

Comment: In some Shiva temples, it is performed every monday  but not on large scale.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general Lord Shiva loves Anna(rice) for Naivedya and also anna daanas(charity).

[This](http://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/lingapurana/bookview.php?chapnum=14) chapter of Linga Purana states:

> As for Naivedya, ‘Shuddhhaanna’ would satisfy Maha Deva; in fact,
>   ‘Anna Daana’ is one significant charity to the needy that Shiva is
>   always desirous of on any day, **especially on Pouranamasi**.

**If this anna abhishekam is done every poornima [full moon] or on selected months poornima only? If so which months?**

The  above passage shows that Lord Shiva loves anna charity specially on Purnimas.The following passage from the same Purana shows that it is of special significance in the Karthika month:

> Kartika Month: **The entire month is of signifinance and daily
>   Shivaarchana-Abhisheka with Sacred water, Milk, Coconut water, Curd,
>   Ghee, Chandana, and Bhasma** with Maha Nyasa Purvaka, Maha Rudra Purvaka
>   Snaanaas to Shiva Linga, Day long fasting and Alpaahara in the nights,
>   complete abstinence, Bhu Shayana and various sacrifices should be in
>   place; all kinds of Daanaas on anyday or as many days  are encouraged
>   in the Month and similarly Pandita Seva of any kind would be fruitful
>   in the Month. **Emphasis is stressed on Anna Daanaas during the month.**

Shiva Pujas ,Rudraabhisekhams are of special significance on Purnima Tithis in general & not just on the Karthika Purnima.

The rewards of performing Shiva Puja,Abhisekhams ,Vratas etc on  Purnimas of various months,given in [this](http://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/lingapurana/bookview.php?chapnum=14) Linga Purana chapter, are as follows:

> Shiva Vratas were also prescribed by Nandi Deva to Skanda as follows: 
>   **Pushya Purnami**: Shiva Pujaabhisheka with Ghrita, Ksheera, Dadhi etc  followed by Brahmana bhojana and Godaana , Ratri bhojana;
>   **Phala: Brahmaloka Prapti**.
>
> **Chaitra Purnima**: Shiva Pujaabhisheka, Raatri bhojana of rice and ghee, Brahmana Bhojana and daana of two white cows
>
> **Vaishakha Purnami**: Shiva Pujaabhisheka with Panchagavyas, Ratri bhojana, Brahmana Bhojana and Go-Daana; **Phala: Ashwamedha Yagna**
>
> **Jeyshtha Purnima**: Shiva Pujaabhisheka, Ratri Bhojana, Brahmana Seva and Dhumravarna Godaana; **Phala: Vaayu loka prapti**
>
> **Ashadha Purnima**: Shiva Pujabhisheka, Ratri bhojana, Brahmana Seva, Gaura varna Godaana; **Phala: Varuna Loka**
>
> **Shravana Purnima**: Shiva Pujaabhisheka, Ratri Bhojana, Vrushabha daana; **Phala:Vayu loka**
>
> **Bhadrapada Purnima:** Havana, Abhishka and Puja; Veda Parayana, Brahmana puja, Vrishabha dwaya daana **Phala: Yaksha loka Rajastwa**.
>
> **Ashviyuja Purnima**: Shiva Pujaabhisheka, day long fast, Brahmana
>   Bhojana and Nila Varna Vishabha daana. **Phala: Ishana loka prapti**.
>
> **Kartika Month**: The entire month is of signifinance and daily Shivaarchana-Abhisheka with Sacred water, Milk, Coconut water, Curd,
>   Ghee, Chandana, and Bhasma with Maha Nyasa Purvaka, Maha Rudra Purvaka
>   Snaanaas to Shiva Linga, Day long fasting and Alpaahara in the nights,
>   complete abstinence, Bhu Shayana and various sacrifices should be in
>   place; all kinds of Daanaas on anyday or as many days  are encouraged
>   in the Month and similarly Pandita Seva of any kind would be fruitful
>   in the Month. Emphasis is stressed on Anna Daanaas during the month.
>   **Phala: Surya Loka Prapti.**
>
> **Margasirsha** Month is considered an an extension of the previous month when again austerities would spill over from the previous month;
>   Upavaasaas, Shiva worship by way of Abhishekas, Brahmana Sevas,  Anna
>   and other kinds of daanaas especially to Daridras, would be of
>   significance and the Phala would be of **Chandra loka prapti.**

Comment: @Rickross--If a person observes strictly what you have mentioned in the respective months can he attain prapti in all lokas? How he will live in all lokas? For specific months he will n ein surya loka and for some months he will be in varuna loka.BTW what is the difference between  brahmana seva and brahmana puja?

Comment: Firstly all that was not my opinion..they are so told in scriptures...i believe in scriptures blindly because they are words of Gods/Saints..so i don't seek rational reasons as such..secondly if someone observes all the months then he mite get a higher reward which is not mentioned in that chapter...Regarding Brahman Puja/seva i don't see much differences...charity to Brhamins.washing his feets,offering of lights.artha,cows,vastra etc to him are the things i guess

Comment: It is not any human's opinion. Whatever given in smritis and puranans you are reproducing . You can refer and clear my doubts which I asked thru comment.

Comment: @ParthasarathyRaghavan I said all that because u said-**what you have mentioned in the respective months**..so firstly i have not said..Linga pUrana said so..Anyways if someone performs all the months then he will probably get a reward that is sum total of the Punyas which is equal to that of all those Loka Praptis....

Comment: U said means not on your own. Referring thru sources what I meant u said.